# Plotly dash callback to one output with different input functionalities

Tags: sql, python-3.x, visualization, plotly-dash

I'm new to Plotly Dash and wanted to design a dash for the following app but couldn't find how to solve an issue that I'm facing.

Here's the scenario: I have a SQL table with the following columns: 'date' (datetime), 'type' (varchar), 'item' (varchar), 'item-group' (varchar), 'county' (varchar), and 'value' (float). In my dashboard, I want users to be able to select any combination of 'date', 'type', 'item-group', and 'country'. Based on their selections, I aim to display the corresponding dataframe as a table in Dash (using any form of tabular visualization).

However, the SQL queries are running significantly slow. I want to fetch data conditioned only on 'date'. This way, the only time that I need to re-run the query is when user changes the default time range, which is so rare (as opposed to 'item-group' and 'county' that users change very frequently and hence, I don't want to re-query for them. I want to have it for all of them).

Here's my challenge: I want to optimize the dashboard to only re-run the SQL query when the user changes the date range. For other user selections, I intend to utilize pandas filtering without re-querying the SQL database. The problem I'm encountering is in setting up the callbacks. I'm struggling to differentiate between callback triggers so that when the user changes the date range, I trigger a re-query, while for other selections, I utilize pandas filtering without re-querying the database. I tried with multiple callback with the same output (table) but it showed me an error. Below, shows an inefficient way, where I re-query after every change. Can you help me achieve the functionality I had in mind?

```
@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'data'),
    [Input('date-range-picker', 'start_date'),
    Input('date-range-picker', 'end_date'),
    Input('type-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('item-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('item-group-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('county-dropdown', 'value')],
)
def update_plots_uncertainty(start_date, end_date, selected_tpye, selected_item, selected_time_group, selected_counties):
    df = pd.read_sql(f"SELECT * FROM t WHERE [date] BETWEEN {start_date} AND {end_date}")
    if selected_tpye:
        df = df[df['type'] == selected_type]
    if selected_item:
        df = df[df['item'] == selected_item]
    if selected_item_group:
        df = df[df['item_group'] == selected_item_group]
    if selected_counties:
        df = df[df['counties'].isin(selected_counties)]
    return df.to_dict('record')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the source of input to a callback using `context`. More information about that can be found here: https://dash.plotly.com/determining-which-callback-input-changed

```
from dash import ctx

@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'data'),
    [Input('date-range-picker', 'start_date'),
    Input('date-range-picker', 'end_date'),
    Input('type-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('item-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('item-group-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('county-dropdown', 'value')],
)
def update_plots_uncertainty(start_date, end_date, selected_tpye, selected_item, selected_time_group, selected_counties):
    context = ctx.triggered_id
    if context == "date-range-picker":
        # SQL query here
    else:
       # Pandas query here
```